# Redshift spectrum timestamp column issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have few files in s3. Used glue data catalog to get the table definition. I have field called `log_time` and I manually set the datatype to timestamp in glue catalog. Now when I query that table from Athena I can see the timestamp values correctly.

Now I go to Redshift spectrum and create an external schema pointing to the schema created by the glue data catalog. I can see the table that are defined there and also when I check the data type of the column I see that it is defined as timestamp. However I run the same query I can in Athena, `log_time` field displays the date part correctly. But for the time part it is all 00:00:00 for all rows.

Any idea?

1. **date value it the file :**2018-12-16 00:47:20.28
2. When i change the field date-type to timestamp manually in glue-data-catalog then then query in Athena i see the value: 2018-12-16 00:47:20.280
3. When I create a Redshift spectrum schema pointing to the data-catalog's schema and then query it, I see the value 2018-12-16 00:00:00

Comment: If you cast it to string in the query, does it show the correct value?

Comment: what is the actual raw value on the csv?

Comment: added the original value and value in athena and Redshift spectrum to my original message.